# Azure Web Role X-Frame-Options

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, x-frame-options

I have a web application that is hosted by azure as a web role. The application is installed on two sub domains, QA and Production, the QA environment has the X-Frame-Options set to deny, but the production environment does not.

Currently the same code is deployed to each environment, so it must be a configuration option. I can't find anywhere in the web app where the XFO headers are set. Where else might the configuration be set?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but still no answer so...
You can set it in the web.config like this:

```
<customHeaders>
    <clear/>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM youruri" />
  </customHeaders>
```

Comment: where exactly do you place that? is it after rewrite? or after system.webserver or after configuration