# angular azure static web app DOMException

Tags: angular, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have a webapp (made with angular) which displays content (html) from an external api (azure function) in an iframe. the SPA is hosted on azure static web app.

when i open the page locally, it works. the iframe shows me the correct content.
as soon as i deploy the website, i get the following error message:

> DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'document' from
> 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "xy.domain.com" from accessing a
> cross-origin frame.

To make this work locally, I had to create a proxy.conf.json with the following content:

```
{
  "/api/myendpoint": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:7071",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {
      "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
  }
}
```

is this also available for azure static web app ? i've tried it with following proxy.conf.json, but it doesn't work

```
{
  "/api/myendpoint": {
    "target": "https://myendpointXXX.azurewebsites.net/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's looks like "X-Frame-Options" blocking this, maybe this old answer helps to you [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876802/6158032)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering relates to the Same-Origin Policy, a security measure in web browsers preventing pages from requesting data from a different domain.

To fix this, set up **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** for your **Azure Function and Azure Static Web app**:-

[image]

As for proxy setups, **Azure Static Web Apps doesn't support** the **`proxy.conf.json`** file. Instead, you can use **`routes.json`** to configure routing rules.

***You can directly add the Function Trigger manually or directly include it in your source code.***

***With Source code - [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=angular). :-***

New Folder with **`api`** is created with the Function Files:-

[image]

Update your **`_src/app/app.module.ts`** to call the function in the Front End:-

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And update **`_src/app/app.component.ts_`** to fetch the text from API and display it in the Front page:-

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div>{{message}}</div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  message = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/message')
      .subscribe((resp: any) => this.message = resp.text);
  }
}
```

Install all the **npm packages** and build your app, **`dist`** folder will be created, ***Deploy the dist folder as App location into your Azure Static Web app:-***

```bash
npm install
npm run build --prod
```

***Manual Add your Function as an API:-***

[image]

Call the API from your static App by adding your Function URL code:-

***URL:-***

```http
https://siliconfuncjsangular.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=JMj1rGcBOscBzHSyN_zIfLgtnzsX0ixqOYDpcb_SPLsfAzFu1V_EwQ==
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Azure Static Web App remove API break site - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262221/azure-static-web-app-remove-api-break-site/77270658#77270658)