# How to integrate an Express.js project with Azure Functions in a single repository?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-functions

I have an Express.js project deployed as a web app to Microsoft Azure. I'm looking to automate some tasks using Azure Functions. These tasks, such as sending reminders, are closely connected to the Express backend itself.

I'd like to maintain a single codebase for both the Express.js app and the Azure Functions. How can I achieve this integration effectively? Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for setting up such a workflow?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can create a [nodejs Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/develop-serverless-apps?tabs=v4-ts) and add it in a  api folder similar to this [Github repository](https://github.com/staticwebdev/vanilla-api/tree/main/api) and deploy this in your Azure web app. If your web app is static, You can directly add Function app in the Azure static web app, Refer my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567587/angular-azure-static-web-app-domexception/77599077#) which is a sample for angular app

Comment: Refer this Github repository as a sample:- https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer for the benefit of the community:-

You can create a [nodejs Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/develop-serverless-apps?tabs=v4-ts) and add it in a api folder similar to this [Github repository](https://github.com/staticwebdev/vanilla-api/tree/main/api) and deploy this in your Azure web app. If your web app is static, You can directly add Function app in the Azure static web app, Refer my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567587/angular-azure-static-web-app-domexception/77599077#) which is a sample for angular app.

For **Azure Static Web App**, You can manually add the already Deployed ***Function API*** or Add the Function API in the code itself:-

[image]

One more option is to refer this [azure-function-express/src at master · yvele/azure-function-express (github.com)](https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express/tree/master/src) github repository Function code is integrated in the Express App.